# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'GIAC'

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to perform a K Means Clustering on a set of data that all texts. I have tried these lines of code and I am getting an error saying "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'GIAC'".

I think the program is still having problems converting my text into vectors to be able to perform a clustering.

I really do not know how to solve this.

Here are the lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

Cert = pd.read_csv('Certification.csv')

X = Cert.iloc[:,:].values

wcss =[]

for i in range(1,5):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init='k-means++', random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plot.plot(range(1,5),wcss)
plot.title('Elbow Method')
plot.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
plot.ylabel('WCSS')
plot.show()
```

I also have attached a screenshot of the error message.[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ9dZ.png)

enter code here

Comment: Scikit Learn can only use numbers... Inside Scikit Learn is a bunch of multiplication, division, matrix operations... what do you think happens when it's all text?

Answer (score 1):

K-means requires your data to be continuous variables.

Clearly, `'GIAC'` is *not* a number, is it?

K-means cannot be used on this data. You'd need to do one-hot encoding or similar, but that comes with it's very own set of problems with k-means... Usually when you have data with values such as `'GIAC'` there just is *no* sound way to cluster the data in a statistically meaningful way. Too many heuristic choice along he way to get a result, that you could get pretty much any other result, too. Try to approach the problem mathematically, not with copy&pasting code.

Comment: I got that resolved.
But I have still have a major problem.
I have two CSV dataset which are full of strings. I am trying to preprocess the data by removing punctuation and stop words. Then, perform a Means Clustering between the two documents.

However, I cannot figure out how to preprocess the data. I have try using the nlkt class for removing stop words and the split but somehow, I keep getting an error message or the other.

Do you have any suggestions?